# Linux Unknown executable asking to make executable every time

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm running Mint 17.1 and every time I launch a program with an "Unknown" type it asks me if I want to open it with a program or make it an executable and run. It's annoying because I gave it the x property for a reason but it still asks every time. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of types the shell/kernel can run.  Setting the `x` (executable) bit on the file permissions will allow files contain known types to execute.

You can test file type with the `file` command.  If this identifies the file as unknown, it likely can't be run by name.

Scripts can begin with a specially formatted comment known as a bang path.  This allow the shell to select the correct script interpreter.  For a python script the bang path might be one of these:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Scripts with bang paths will fail if the desired interpreter can't be found at the specified location.  The second option uses the `env` program to locate the interpreter on the path.

Depending on the ownership of the file, you may not be able to make the file executable.  If you don't own the file you won't be able to mark it executable.   However you can use `sudo` and `chmod` to able you to mark it executable.  (You will need to be able to run `sudo`.  To mark a file named `testfile` executable try the command:

```
sudo chmod +x testfile
```

Properly built `.jar` files can be run as an executable if you have a Java runtime installed.  However, the default Mint installation is cautious about starting them.  You can make it execute when you double click changing the laucher configuration.  Right click the *.jar file > Open with other application > Use a custom command > enter "java -jar" and make sure "use as default for this kind of file" is marked.  Alternatively you can create a launcher script.  See the [Linux Mint Forums articl](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=172661)e for more details.

Comment: The file type is unknown however if I double click it it asks me what I want to do and if I say make executable and run it'll open the program but I don't want to do that every time and it has the executable bit

Comment: @Scoopta If you don't own the file you can't mark it executable.  I've edited my answer to add a solution in this case.

Comment: I do own the file and it has the x property. Even with the property it asks me every single time. If I right click and go to properties it shows it as being executable and when I run ls -l it has the x permission.

Comment: @Scoopta What are you launching and how? I suspect what is really happening is not what you think is happening. Please update your question.

Comment: I am launching the dogecoin core wallet. The other thing that does it is srware iron.